# Owl Carousel Animation Speed

Tags: css, animation

I have an Owl Carousel about halfway down the page here: https://www.lakeshoresup.com/product/pathfinder/

I would like to slow down the fade animation speed. I have tried the SlideSpeed and PaginationSpeed in the owl jQuery and it didn't work:

```
<script>
    jQuery(window).on("load", function(){
      jQuery('.carousel-wrapper .owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        items: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplayTimeout: <?php if(!$autotimer) {echo 3000;} else {echo $autotimer;} ?>,
        nav: true,
        loop: true,
        animateOut: 'fadeOut',
        animateIn: 'fadeIn',
        slideSpeed: 3000,
        paginationSpeed: 3000,
        navText: ['<span>prev</span>', '<span>next</span>']
      });
    });
```

I also tried animation-duration in the css:

```
.owl-caraousel .animated { 
  animation-duration: 3000ms !important;
 }
```

Any ideas on how to slow this animation down. We are using fadeIn and fadeOut which look like this:

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.fadeIn {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
}
```

Comment: In this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26443205/owl-carousel-slidespeed-not-working I found that the solution `.owl-carousel .owl-item {animation-duration: 3s !important;}` could work for you.

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I was just using the wrong class.

Answer (score 4):

Use `smartSpeed:1500` in JavaScript

See it here
https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/animate.html

Answer (score 0):

You can add animation-duration: [number]s; to .fadeIn to change how long the fade lasts.

Answer (score 0):

> I also tried animation-duration in the css:
>
> .owl-caraousel .animated {    animation-duration: 3000ms !important;
> }

Use

```
.owl-carousel .animated {
```

instead of

```
.owl-caraousel .animated {
```